# jQuery not preventing form from being submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to prevent a form from being submitted using jQuery and instead run a function when the user wants to submit.

Here's my forms markup:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="msg-form">
    <p><textarea name="msg"></textarea><input type="submit" value="Send"></p>
</form>
```

And my Javascript code:

```
$('#msg-form').submit(function() {
    return false;
}
```

However, when I press the submit button, the form still gets sent and the page refreshes. How can I properly prevent the form from submitting?

Comment: you're missing a ```)```  at the end. i assume that's not the case in your real code? also, if you put an ```alert("form submitted!")``` in your submit callback, does it ever get called ?

Comment: Sorry, I must of screwed that up when I was playing with the formatting for the post. My real code has no syntax errors, and if I test it with an alert I never see the alert, the page just gets refreshed.

Comment: You will probably need to share some more of your code than just this, because [it works fine with proper syntax](http://jsfiddle.net/869cX/).

Comment: This code should not submit the form. You're doing all right. Are you sure you tested it properly?

Comment: Make sure your code gets called (meaning that the submit callback is really registered), and it really select the right form (`$('#msg-form').length == 1`)

Comment: @Justinᚅᚔᚈᚄᚒᚔ: Do you see select on the left of jsFiddle's interface, where the "onLoad" option is selected? This means the code you pasted into jsfiddle is in fact passed into `$(window).load()` as parameter. One should be aware of that when trying to implement some script.

Comment: @Tadeck: Yes, I'm aware of that option. If this code was included in the `<head>` rather than in onLoad or onDomReady, it would run prior to `msg-form` being there and thus be ineffective.

Comment: @Justinᚅᚔᚈᚄᚒᚔ: This is what I am saying, it may have proper syntax, but still may not work, if placed in different places (where the form with `msg-form` ID has not been found). The solution may be just attaching it as event handler for `load` or `domready` events. That is all, I believe.

Comment: @Tadeck, I see your point. Good call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the event handler is not even executed, thus I assume the form could not have been found. Try enclosing your code within handler executed when the DOM is ready. In jQuery it can be simply done like that:

```
$(function(){
    $('#msg-form').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // code executed when user tries to submit the form
    });
});
```

Also, as you can see above, you can prevent default behaviour of the form when it is being submitted.

Answer (score 1):

The `submit` event is not actually being bound to the form element. You may have forgotten to bind it after the DOM was loaded!

Put the event binding inside of `$(document).ready(function() {` or load the script at the bottom of the page (after all of the elements have loaded).

Answer (score 0):

`$('#msg-form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  });`

Answer (score 0):

You could not give the users a real submit button and only submit the form using JS after validation:

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post" id="msg-form">
    <p><textarea name="msg"></textarea><input id="submit" type="button" value="Send"></p>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
    // validate
    $('#msg-form')[0].submit();
});
```

Comment: This is not the real problem.

Comment: It may not be a solution his approach but it's an alternate approach to the same problem that I know works.

Comment: @anstosa: In this specific case it probably will not work either. Tell you why I know? Because if you put it in `<head>`, without passing the script to be executed as handler for `ondomready` or `onload`, it will not find `#submit`, as the code will be executed before the button is available to be retrieved.

Comment: @zizozu these are just code snippets, not meant to be a complete solution. One could attach such a listener in the head with `$(document).on('click', '#submit', function() { \\do stuff });` This is [the proper way to do it in jQuery 1.7+](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: @anstosa: This is definitely not the proper way to do it, if you have `#submit` available as soon as when the DOM is ready :) Why? Because it listens on the events within the whole document (it is called **event delegation**, which involves **event bubbling** and checks for the target of the event). If you _really_ need to use event delegation (which is true sometimes), you should really replace `document` with the selector for the element you are sure will preserve attached events, and you are sure the `#submit` element will appear inside it (if ever). That way you limit your impact.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#msg-form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
<form action='' onsubmit="return false;">
```

As does this

```
<form action='' onsubmit="doSomeWork();return false;">
```

Comment: This is very ugly solution, hard to maintain in larger applications.